# Suppress Typescript warnings

Tags: javascript, typescript, compiler-errors, suppress-warnings

I have following typescript code:

```
 private addBrowserNameAsCssClassToHtmlTag(): void {
  var rootElement = angular.element(document.querySelector("html"));
  if (this.isOpera()) {
    rootElement.addClass("opera-browser");
  } else if (this.isFirefox()) {
    rootElement.addClass("firefox-browser");
  } else if (this.isSafari()) {
    rootElement.addClass("safari-browser");
  } else if (this.isIE()) {
    rootElement.addClass("ie-browser");
  } else if (this.isChrome()) {
    rootElement.addClass("chrome-browser");
  }
}

private isOpera(): boolean {
  return (!!(<any>window).opr && !!(<any>opr).addons) || !!window.opera || navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' OPR/') >= 0;
}

private isFirefox(): boolean {
  //noinspection TypeScriptUnresolvedVariable
  return typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';
}

private isSafari(): boolean {
  return /constructor/i.test(window.HTMLElement) || ((p): boolean => {
      return p.toString() === "[object SafariRemoteNotification]";
    })(!window['safari'] || safari.pushNotification);
}

private isIE(): boolean {
  return /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!window.document.documentMode;
}

private isChrome(): boolean {
  return !!window.chrome && !!window.chrome.webstore;
}
```

Code works fine but the problem is that it generates compile time errors:

```
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'opr'.
error TS2339: Property 'opera' does not exist on type 'Window'.
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'InstallTrigger'.
error TS2339: Property 'HTMLElement' does not exist on type 'Window'.
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'safari'.
error TS2339: Property 'documentMode' does not exist on type 'Document'.
error TS2339: Property 'chrome' does not exist on type 'Window'.
error TS2339: Property 'chrome' does not exist on type 'Window'.
```

If I wrote in plain javascript I wouldn't have any problem. How can I suppress compiler warnings concerning this part of code? Or maybe there is better solution which I don't know?

Answer (score 14):

A solution:

```
declare const InstallTrigger: any;

class Abc {
    private addBrowserNameAsCssClassToHtmlTag(): void {
        var rootElement = angular.element(document.querySelector("html"));
        if (this.isOpera()) {
            rootElement.addClass("opera-browser");
        } else if (this.isFirefox()) {
            rootElement.addClass("firefox-browser");
        } else if (this.isSafari()) {
            rootElement.addClass("safari-browser");
        } else if (this.isIE()) {
            rootElement.addClass("ie-browser");
        } else if (this.isChrome()) {
            rootElement.addClass("chrome-browser");
        }
    }

    private isOpera(): boolean {
        return (!!window['opr'] && !!window['opr'].addons) || !!window['opera'] || navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' OPR/') >= 0;
    }

    private isFirefox(): boolean {
        //noinspection TypeScriptUnresolvedVariable
        return typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';
    }

    private isSafari(): boolean {
        return /constructor/i.test(window['HTMLElement']) || ((p): boolean => {
            return p.toString() === "[object SafariRemoteNotification]";
        })(!window['safari'] || window['safari'].pushNotification);
    }

    private isIE(): boolean {
        return /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!window.document['documentMode'];
    }

    private isChrome(): boolean {
        return !!window['chrome'] && !!window['chrome'].webstore;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Quick and dirty answer, use bracket notation, they are not type checked in TS

```
window["opera"]
```

Another option is to extend the global interfaces, when you build typescript the compiler includes a "base" .d.ts file, they are lib.d.ts or if targeting es6 its lib.es6.d.ts. To extends the global interfaces create a new .d.ts file. myGlobalExtentions.d.ts for example and include that in your build.

```
interface Window {
    opera:string;   
}

interface Document {
    documentMode:string;   
}
```

Comment: IMO it's not a good idea to modify the definition of `Window` or `Document`. These extra members are not used here. They are just checked in order to determine which is the browser. The dirty trick of bracket notation is more adapted here.

Comment: I agree that option 1 with bracket notations is the best here, just wanted to demonstrate the two available options.

Comment: The issue here is that InstallTrigger cannot be solved in this way. I believe that Paleo's answer addresses all of the concerns here.

Answer (score 3):

It is 2022 now;
you can use -

```
// @ts-ignore
```

(copy that along with the `//`)

see also

```
// @ts-nocheck
```

which might fit in some cases